# c# win 10 app: Bold text with textpointer in richtextbolck

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal

I develop an Windows 10 universal App!

I have an rtb, where I want to bold e.g. two word:

```
Hello; Bye
```

The text from the rtb (in an run) is:

```
Hello and Bye
```

Now I want to bold it, for this I wanted to use Textpointers:

```
public void Select(
TextPointer start, 
TextPointer end
);

TextPointer pointer = run.ContentStart;

TextPointer start = pointer.GetPositionAtOffset(0, LogicalDirection.Forward);
TextPointer end = start.GetPositionAtOffset(5, LogicalDirection.Forward);

rtb.Select (start,end);
```

But after that I dont know how to bold the selected text.
Every Suggestion from Google is like this:

```
Bold boldx = new Bold(start, end);
```

Now the Problem is, that Bold not include an constructor, which assume 3 Arguments...

The "new front" Thing also dont work, couse it dont find "font".

Any ideas?
thx for help

Answer (score 0):

The Bold class can be used like that :

```
var boldx = new Bold();
boldx.ContentStart = start;
boldx.ContentEnd = end;
```

Comment: Sry to say this, but in my Windows 10 app is .contentStart and End only to get the value... Do you have any Suggestion for this?

Comment: can you post a working code and be more explicit about the result you want please ?

Comment: Check the updated Question, or do I miss an importent Information?

Comment: Did you know this issue?